# Indicate which OS a blackberry application will support

Tags: blackberry

Is there a way I can indicate to users who have downloaded a blackberry application I've built that it only supports a particular OS?

I've written an app that's designed to run on OS 5+ and I'd like to explicitly tell users of previous versions that their OS is not supported, and perhaps suggest to them what can be done to upgrade their handset OSes

Comment: Slightly related to this - to check for specific apps on device 
    handle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_qm_platform"); 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/New-BBM6-Module-net-rim-bb-qm-platform-not-found/td-p/1067551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky one.

You can limit on the BlackBerry App World which OS/Devices the app is suitable for, which is probably the best way.

If you are actually talking about throwing a warning on your app, I guess you could use [DeviceInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html), but I doubt your app will start-up if you are using any 5.0 specific modules.

Sorry :(